# How to get the sum of a list of numbers with recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I want to sum numbers with a recursive function, i.e.

```
getSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

should return 1+2+3+4+5 == 15

I'm not an expert in recursive functions, I've tried something like:

```
def getSum(piece):
    for i in piece
        suc += getSum(i)
```

The problem is that I can't loop through integers. I'm sure this is a quite easy task but I really can't figure it out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need to loop. Recursion will do that for you.

```
def getSum(piece):
    if len(piece)==0:
        return 0
    else:
        return piece[0] + getSum(piece[1:]) 
print getSum([1, 3, 4, 2, 5])
```

Comment: And what if I want to check sum after every call of function getSum?So I wanna check f.e. if sum>9: do something ?

Answer (score 8):

I think it is a little nicer without explicitly checking the length:

```
def getSum(piece):
    return piece[0] + getSum(piece[1:]) if piece else 0
```

Demo:

```
>>> getSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
15
```

Answer (score 3):

For academic purposes (learning Python) you could use recursion:

```
def getSum(iterable):
    if not iterable:
        return 0  # End of recursion
    else:
        return iterable[0] + getSum(iterable[1:])  # Recursion step
```

But you shouldn't use recursion in real production code. It's not efficient and the code much less clear then with using built-ins. For this case you do not need neither recursion nor loop. Just use built-in [sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
>>>a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>sum(a) 
15
```

Comment: But I have to do it with recursion :P

Comment: Don't do it with recursion in production code. For academic purposes it could be OK, but don't dot it in real life.

Comment: uselpa, Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce also.
The function reduce(func, seq) continually applies the function func() to the sequence seq. It returns a single value.

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, range(1,6))
```

Answer (score 1):

if your list is more complex than a simple list , for example:

```
mylist = [1,-10,[[2,[3]],7.3],[[[[[[[[[-5]]]],2]]],1],4]]
```

you should use this code:

```
mylist = [1,-10,[[2,[3]],7.3],[[[[[[[[[-5]]]],2]]],1],4]]

def getSum(piece):
    if len(piece)==0:
        return 0
    elif type(piece[0]) is list:
        return getSum(piece[0]) + getSum(piece[1:])
    else:
        return piece[0] + getSum(piece[1:]) 
        
print(getSum(mylist))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, in a more "Pythonic" way:

```
suml = lambda l: l[0] + suml(l[1:]) if l else 0

print(suml(range(101)))
```

## Output: 5050

Answer (score 0):

using recursion and pop function

```
def getSum(piece):
    return piece.pop() + getSum(piece) if piece else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this:

```
def rec_sum(array):
  total = 0
  if len(array):
    total += array.pop(0) + rec_sum(array)
  return total
```

Comment: Seems alright. But notice that this has to shift the entire list every time we pops off the start, it has to move everything one element over. It may be better with just `array.pop()` which pops off the last. Of course recursion is unnecessary anyway but the OP asks for this.